# Regarding output to mysql database using barnyard 2

Tags: mysql

While trying to output unified2 format into mysql database using Barnyard2, the Source or destination IP addresses in the database come in the format "3232240901" instead of 192.168.1.0(just in case)..How do I fix it?

Comment: What is "unified2 format"?  What's "Barnyard2"?

Comment: 3232240901 is 192.168.21.5 not 192.168.1.0

Comment: "3232240901" is just another way to store IPv4 addresses.  It's just an integer instead of "192.168.21.5".  You can use [`INET_NTOA()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa) to convert this to the format you want.